# Focus Mobile Browser with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, signalr

I need to show turn-by-turn navigation on my mobile site (a SignalR project. just Chrome). I googled it. But there is not (or not not but i didn't found usefull something) api for this. So i put the a tag with href="google.location=q.."
It opens Google Maps.
I checked SignalR. Connection ok even if page is running background. I can send a message from server to this client. Message received. But user cannot show. (Because Google Maps is open.:))

Can i show alert, notification or focus browser (or close googlemaps) with javascriptly when browser isn't active?

```
hub.client.receivemessage = function (from, msj) {
                //alert or something that will provide to open browser 
            };
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: you should be able to push notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the user can't read the notification because google maps is in the way. Html5 supports desktop notifications and can be displayed above all content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification has the documentation.